# Paypal button is not showing in Sale Order and Accounting Invoice odoo?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8

Once i installed payment_paypal module, still it is not showing after confirm the sale order and validate the invoice.

Comment: i think you can use paypal option from frontend i.e., through website-> shop -> payment, there you can select the type of payment acquirer. In sale_order it will show only the details that the payment was made using paypal through Payment Acquirer field under Total field. we cannot select here in the sale_order.

Comment: In website, payment acquirer button is showing but it's not showing in confirmed sale_order as well as validated invoice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to give the Rights of "View Online Payment Options" in the user form, after that user will able to see the payment button in sale_order as well as invoice also and also see in a website.